# WordPress meta title and description with Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, metadata, advanced-custom-fields

I have a fully working code to collect the data of 2 meta fields (title and description) on all pages in case the auto generated (or empty) meta is not suitable. It works on every page exact 2:

– The WordPress blog overview (archive)
– The WooCommerce shop page (also archive page)

The 2 ACF fields within the pages look like to be totally ignored.

Any reason for that? And how to overwrite this behavior?

I understand that both pages are like kinda system pages where I can’t directly edit the content but I do want to edit the generated (or empty) meta data.

Here’s the working code (except for the 2 archive pages):

```
// Add social media friendly meta tags
function yl_add_meta_tags_to_wp_head() {

    setup_postdata( $post );

    $custom_meta_title          = get_field('yl_meta_title' );
    $custom_meta_description    = get_field( 'yl_meta_description' );

    if ($custom_meta_title) {
        $meta_title = $custom_meta_title;
    } else {
        $meta_title = get_the_title();
    }

    if ($custom_meta_description) {
        $meta_description = $custom_meta_description;
    } else {
        $meta_description = substr(wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_excerpt()),0,150) . '...';
    }

    echo '
        <meta name="meta_name" content="' . $meta_title . '" />
        <meta name="description" content="' . $meta_description . '" />
    ';

}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'yl_add_meta_tags_to_wp_head', 1, 1 );
```

EDIT:
Let me be more clear: Why are the ACF fields in my shop page (backend) filled with data but complete ignored in the frontend source code...? (This behavior only happens on shop and archive pages).

Comment: Could be because your theme uses separate archive template and template header.
Check your theme files and see if archive header file has <?php wp_head(); ?> method call.

Comment: Let me be more clear: Why are the ACF fields in my shop page (backend) filled with data but complete ignored in the frontend source code...?